# onPause() Android

Tags: android, onpause

I have an app that connects to an URL every X seconds in an onPostExecute of a library that I had done. When I close the app or go back with the back button, it must stop with an override of the `onPause()` method on the main activity class.
I want to control this with my own library to facilitate the creation of class for new developers, but if I override it on the library `onPause()` method, it continues making connections.
There's a way to do these on my library?

Here my code on the main class:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLib.stopResource();
    myLib.flagRefresh = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        myLib.stopResource();
        myLib.flagRefresh = false;
        super.onBackPressed();
        return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `onStop()` instead of `onPause()`, which is called whenever the activity is not shown on screen but is still running, i.e. when the screen goes black. Instead of overwriting `onKeyDown()` it is better to use `onBackPressed()` method, however if you place your current code of `onPause()` inside `onStop()` it would not be required to overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, it's better now, but my problem continues. With other words, i have a class that calls to another class hosted on my library and i want to catch these events on it. If i use an intent call, it works, but if i make the call like this: myLib = new Lib(attr); [attr is the atributes that i need inside] when i go back, my library doesn't catch the events and continues making connections

Comment: I am afraid we have not enough information about the internals of your library and it seems a problem with your library, not your activity. If your library is openning connections and it keeps opening them after you call stopResource() it is a problem with your library.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with my library because i can't catch this events on the library when i go out of it and i want to catch this events on the library, not on the activity. is it posible?

Comment: Everything is possible. You can use a plain listener interface (methods implemented by the activity that the library would call back, not only to return a result, but also to report an error). However this is not related to Android at all, it is just plain basic Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see it is to derive a new class from Activity supporting your library.
But this approach will run into a permutational explosion.
Any specialist standard activity needs a MyLib-variant too.
(ListActivity, FragmentActivity, and so on)

```
class MyLibActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onPause() ..

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)..

}
```

So it's probably the best to offer just a support for the pure activity.

Comment: I've done this, but my library doesn't catch it. I think that it's because it is running in background

Comment: When your lib is implemented as a service you to do the correct communications. Regardless whether the code is part of the lib or not.