# Unable to stop activity android

Tags: android, call, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayer does not pause when a phone call is received. So I have added the on onStop, it works but then if I try to go back with the back button or back button in the action bar to go to main menu of app, it just crashes. If anyone can help would be great! Only beginner

Class

```
public class player1 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();
boolean flag = true;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_1);
        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound01;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound02;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound03;
        // Listeners
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player1.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); ;         
             progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
             progressBar.setProgress(0);
             progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
             new Thread(this).start();

         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
              mp.seekTo(0);

            }
        });

        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                     mp.pause();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
                  } else {
                     mp.start();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);

                  }

               }
            });
   }
   static boolean runThread = true;
   public void run() {
        while ( runThread )  {
              int currentPosition=0;
              int total = mp.getDuration();
              if ( mp != null && currentPosition <= total )  {
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 return;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 return;
              }            
              progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
           } else
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        runThread = false; 
    }
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
           mp.pause();
       }
   }


   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


        if (mp != null)
        if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

       }
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (mp != null){
          if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();
      }

      //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
      //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
      super.onBackPressed(); 
    }

    }
```

Error

```
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.apps.seconds/com.apps.seconds.player1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3463)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3517)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.apps.seconds.player1.onStop(player1.java:154)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1212)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5275)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3458)
  09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: OnStop gets executed after onBackPressed, you are releasing the mp object and then you are trying to pause it

Comment: So What could I do to fix this?

Comment: just comment the onBackPresed and check out if works or put the whole thing in the onPause

Comment: Sorry don't know what your mean by that sorry only a beginner. Could you show me with my code in a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use this

```
  @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (mp != null){
          if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();
      }
```

you can use on resume to resume the music play

```
protected void onResume()
    {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
```

You must learn activity LifeCycle
or refer my Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703841/call-method-on-activity-load-android)

Comment: @user only pause is ok

Comment: Thanks that work! The thing is after the phone call the audio is paused but the button is showing that its playing so how would I make it so the pause button changes back to play.

Comment: Thanks so much, been much help :D

Answer (score 1):

> 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   09-12 14:52:49.755:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)

`IllegalStateException` exception occurred  because internal player has already been released when you back pressed and you are calling `isPlaying` after that..

[Refer here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

There are some explanation here : 
[onPause() Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784942/onpause-android)

or on the official website you have the event workflow which is pretty useful